# ilike search working irregularly with characters "ÅÄÖ"

Tags: mysql

Alright, so I've got a pretty weird error.

Say I have the string "Ön Åsa Äpple föll ner i sjön"

```
query      |result
Ön         |Found
ÖN         |Found
ön         |Found
<same pattern works with Åsa and Äpple as well>

föll       |Found
Föll       |Found
FÖLL       |Not found
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. Clearly searching with capital ÅÄÖ works, but for some reason not when the ÅÄÖ-character is not the first letter of a word?

I have a Rails application and a MYSQL database. 
This is the corresponding code:

```
dataset = DB[category_class.table_name.to_sym]
    dataset = dataset.where(:headline.ilike("%" + headline + "%")) if headline.present?
```

I'd be very grateful for any comments or answers that leads me in the right direction to solving this problem.

Regards, Emil

Comment: `show create table YOUR_TABLE`, what is the encoding used for your mysql table ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something to do with the way the `utf8_unicode_ci` collation compares strings. A **collation** is a collection of rules that determine when two strings are considered "the same", and when they are not; it also determines the order in which strings are sorted.

To see the collations for the `utf8` character set, issue `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8'`. You will see that there are a variety of language-specific collations. These don't limit the values you can store in the column`*` but rather impose string comparison rules tailored towards text that is expected to be primarily in a specific language. Alternatively, you can use the `utf8_general_ci` collation which ignores accents entirely.

`*` Although if unique keys are involved, they might change whether one value is considered a duplicate of another or not.